# how can i use interact.js for template design

Tags: php, jquery, interact.js

here is the link which i want to use for template design http://interactjs.io/
i can drag the module height from one container into second container and can drag position by using interact.js functionality by using jquery and php... record should be update ib database on drop... see screen below for more detail

[see screenshot for more help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaRUQ.png)

need solution with jquery and PHP...interact.js is compulsory :)

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML:
<div class="containerdiv" style="float:left">
<div id="drag-450-180"  class="draggable js-drag">180</div>
<div id="drag-900-180"  class="draggable js-drag">180</div>
<div id="drag-450-240" class="draggable js-drag">240 </div>
<div id="drag-900-240" class="draggable js-drag">240 </div>
<div id="drag-450-360" class="draggable js-drag">360 </div>
<div id="drag-900-360" class="draggable js-drag">360 </div>
<div id="drag-450-480" class="draggable js-drag">360 </div>
<div id="drag-900-480" class="draggable js-drag">360 </div>
</div>
<div class="dropzone-wrapper">
    <div id="drop1" class="dropzone js-drop">Dropzone</div>
</div>
interact('.js-drag')
        .draggable({ 
        restrict: {
              restriction: "parent",
              endOnly: true,
              elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
            }, 
        overlap: 'pointer', 
        inertia: true,
        checker: function (dragEvent,         // related dragmove or dragend
             event,             // Touch, Pointer or Mouse Event
             dropped,           // bool default checker result
             dropzone,          // dropzone Interactable
             dropElement,       // dropzone elemnt
             draggable,         // draggable Interactable
             draggableElement) {// draggable element

            // only allow drops into empty dropzone elements
            return dropped && !dropElement.hasChildNodes();
          }
        })
        .on('dragstart', function (event) {
            event.interaction.x = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-x'), 10) || 0;
            event.interaction.y = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-y'), 10) || 0;

        })
        .on('dragmove', function (event) {
            event.interaction.x += event.dx;
            event.interaction.y += event.dy;
            if (transformProp) {
                event.target.style[transformProp] =
                    'translate(' + event.interaction.x + 'px, ' + event.interaction.y + 'px)';
            }
            else {
                event.target.style.left = event.interaction.x + 'px';
                event.target.style.top  = event.interaction.y + 'px';
            }           
        })
        .on('dragend', function (event) {
           // event.target.setAttribute('data-x', event.interaction.x);
          //  event.target.setAttribute('data-y', event.interaction.y);
            event.target.setAttribute('data-x', 0);
            event.target.setAttribute('data-y', 0);
            event.target.removeAttribute('style');
        });
        interact('.js-drag2')
        .draggable({ 
            restrict: {
              restriction: "parent",
              endOnly: true,
              elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
            } ,
             inertia: true,
            overlap: 0.01,
            checker: function (dragEvent,         // related dragmove or dragend
             event,             // Touch, Pointer or Mouse Event
             dropped,           // bool default checker result
             dropzone,          // dropzone Interactable
             dropElement,       // dropzone elemnt
             draggable,         // draggable Interactable
             draggableElement) {// draggable element

            // only allow drops into empty dropzone elements
            return dropped && !dropElement.hasChildNodes();
          }
        })
        .on('dragstart', function (event) {
            event.interaction.x = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-x'), 10) || 0;
            event.interaction.y = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-y'), 10) || 0;           
        })
        .on('dragmove', function (event) {
            event.interaction.x += event.dx;
            event.interaction.y += event.dy;
            if (transformProp) {
                event.target.style[transformProp] =
                    'translate(' + event.interaction.x + 'px, ' + event.interaction.y + 'px)';
            }
            else {
                event.target.style.left = event.interaction.x + 'px';
                event.target.style.top  = event.interaction.y + 'px';
            }           

        })
        .on('dragend', function (event) {
           event.target.setAttribute('data-x', event.interaction.x);
           event.target.setAttribute('data-y', event.interaction.y);            
        });
```